# multiple NOT LIKE operator on same column with OR condition fails in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Table Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Message](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [created_on] [datetime] NULL,
    [message] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Message] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Values:**

```
1   '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000'   'error occured "BASKET_BALL"'
2   '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000'   'error occured "FOOT_BALL"'
3   '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000'   'I am not involved in like operator'
4   '2014-02-01 00:00:00.000'   'I might be involved'
```

**Query return against the table:**

```
SELECT 
    ID,CREATED_ON,MESSAGE 
FROM 
    MESSAGE
WHERE 
    MESSAGE NOT LIKE '%"FOOT_BALL"%' OR MESSAGE NOT LIKE '%BASKET_BALL%'
    AND CREATED_ON >= '2014-01-01'
```

**Output:**

```
1   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 error occured "BASKET_BALL"
2   2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 error occured "FOOT_BALL"
3   2012-01-01 00:00:00.000 I am not involved in like operator
4   2014-02-01 00:00:00.000 I might be involved
```

**Question:**

Could some one explain why the query returns all the table values when explicitly the date condition is mentioned for greater than 2014 ? I understand by keeping the message condition in bracket it yields proper result. However, like to know why the sql excludes date condition mentioned when the not like operator is not in bracket.

Answer (score 5):

It's because the `AND` operator has [higher precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx) than `OR`. Change to this:

```
SELECT 
    ID,CREATED_ON,MESSAGE 
FROM 
    MESSAGE
WHERE 
    (MESSAGE NOT LIKE '%"FOOT_BALL"%' OR MESSAGE NOT LIKE '%BASKET_BALL%')
    AND CREATED_ON >= '2014-01-01'
```

Depending on what you want maybe the parenthesis should surround the latter part, like so:

```
    MESSAGE NOT LIKE '%"FOOT_BALL"%' OR (MESSAGE NOT LIKE '%BASKET_BALL%'
    AND CREATED_ON >= '2014-01-01')
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment jpw...I understand by placing the parenthesis we can get proper result. But I like to understand the order the sql  executes this condition  MESSAGE NOT LIKE '%"FOOT_BALL"%' OR MESSAGE NOT LIKE '%BASKET_BALL%' AND CREATED_ON >= '2014-01-01'  because the query ignore the date condition all together.

Comment: @RameshM It doesn't ignore the date, but the date and basket_ball conditions are tied together; it matches the first row on the not like football, the second row on the basket_ball and date, the third and fourth rows again on the not like foot_ball.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing parantheses so OR having lower precedence translates as

```
WHERE 
MESSAGE NOT LIKE '%"FOOT_BALL"%' OR (MESSAGE NOT LIKE '%BASKET_BALL%'
AND CREATED_ON >= '2014-01-01')

MESSAGE NOT LIKE '%"FOOT_BALL"%'
```

returs 3 rows, doesnt care about the date

Put both ORs in parentheses.

Comment: Also without braces also lines with FOOT_BALL and with BASKET_BALL are included, as BASKET_BALL != FOOT_BALL -- issue on logical usage of or -... you might were looking for some kind of xor operator